# Dynamic SQL: Retrieving column values from a temp table without stating column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with two columns that I would directly copy to another table without explicitly stating the column names (and ultimately rename these columns).

Temp table:

```
X   Y
x1  y1
x2  y2
x3  y3
```

Desired output:

```
A  B  C  D
x1 y1 X  Y
x2 y2 X  Y
x3 y3 X  Y
```

I assume this has to be done via Dynamic SQL since I'm trying to use the ordinal position to populate my new table. I already have @Column_Name1 and @Column_Name2 that points to the column names of the temp table (but not the actual data) for columns C and D in the desired output table.

Would greatly appreciate if you could provide some of the actual coding as I have very little knowledge of dynamic sql. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Post your table structure you are trying to copy data from.  You could probably do a select into statement I believe but need a bit more info

Comment: Yes. You'll need Dynamic SQL for this so you can build sql into a string. Something like `"INSERT INTO original_table (" + @Column_Name1 + ", " + @Column_Name2 + ") SELECT * FROM temp_table;"` and then execute that with [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)